# Azure AG Listener not accessible from secondary Nodes

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017

We are building PoC SQL 2017 Availability Group up in Azure. This is part of a longer-term plan to both provide resiliency & a path to upgrade in the Spring

I have been able to stand up the AG & failover the databases successfully. Our problem comes with the Listener. I can create this, with no SQL level errors & use from instance acting as the primary. But when I try to use the Listener from the secondary node, it does not work. As the PoC is to investigate replication with Availability Groups, the Listener is a key feature.

The Listener shows up correctly in DNS as a valid Forwarder. Yet when I try for example to PING the listener from a VM other than the primary, it will return the correct IP, but each request times out.

When I check via Server Manager, I can see the various nodes via the “All Servers” tab. The Listener shows up along with the parent Cluster as one of the Servers. But for secondary node the IPv4 address is blank & the manageability message is “Target computer not accessible”.

From researching, we need a VNN, rather than a DNN as we still on SQL 2017. But working with the server team, we have not been able to achieve a workable Listener on any node aside from the Primary. Any ideas or advice regarding what we may have missed or misconfigured would be gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 0):

AG Listeners Single-subnet clusters in Azure don't work the same as on-prem.  On-prem servers control their own IP addresses, but in Azure the platform assigns IP addresses to servers.  If a server configures an IP address that the platform doesn't know about, it will never get any packets.

The traditional solution in Azure is to use an Internal Load Balancer in front of your AG nodes.  The Load Balancer would then probe the nodes to discover which one has the IP up and route the traffic to that node.

The more modern and simpler guidance is to use a multi-subnet cluster and to have the AG listener have a different IP on each node.  That way the cluster will only be listening on one of the IPs and client can simply attempt to connect to both, and succeed in connecting to whichever is online.

See [Tutorial: Prerequisites for availability groups in multiple subnets (SQL Server on Azure VMs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-manually-configure-prerequisites-tutorial-multi-subnet?view=azuresql)

Comment: Thanks David

The issue in end stemmed from the Azure VMs not being in an Availability Set when they were first created.
Not an easy thing to work, took way too long. But this is why we do PoCs to learn these kinds of issues